# cv.glmnet crashing in R studio, when trying to run a multinomial regression with LASSO penalty

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am trying to run `cv.glmnet` with `family="multinomial"`.

However whenever I run it, RStudio crashes. I have also tried just running it from the command line, but this then just quits R.

My response classes are given in matrix from and I have a corresponding feature matrix.
Below I give the code, with the dataset hosted on GitHub:

```
# Loading datasets:
load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_features.rda?raw=true"))
load(url("https://github.com/DylanDijk/RepoA/blob/main/reprod_response.rda?raw=true"))

# Training the model:
model_multinom_cv = glmnet::cv.glmnet(x = reprod_features,  y = reprod_response,
                                      family = "multinomial", alpha = 1)
```